# Parallel Desktop 0.0 KB Reclaimable

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop

I want to increase the size of the virtual hard disk in my  Windows 10 VM using Parallel Desktop, but in configuration I see Reclaimable 0.0 KB. How can I solve this?
[image: Windows 10 VM Settings]

Comment: Reclaimable memory is for memory that was taken up but now is no longer taken up. If you use dynamically sizing drives this shouldn't be an issue though. Check the below answer, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean Hard Disk space, rather than memory.

To do that, you need to be in the Hardware tab, rather than General. The 'Reclaimable' you see in General is just for reclaiming space that's been freed up by deleting things from the virtual disk, not for enlarging it.

The simplest method to use is to set the drive as Expanding - then it will automatically grow to whatever size it needs. Alternatively, you can set a manual size in the same window.

Note, you cannot do this if the OS is suspended, or if you have any Snapshots.

[image]

[image]

If you did mean Memory, that's in the same Tab, in CPU & Memory [limited by how much RAM you do actually have, of course]...

[image]